# Python to read name of the file extension SC2Replay

Tags: python, file, move

I am new to Python and I have problems with reading the file under extension SC2Replay. I have 4 files with names in the same folder:

- Match 2 - G3 - LiquidHerO vs aLive(DayBreak)-Copy-Copy-Copy.SC2Replay
- Match 2 - G2 - LiquidHerO vs aLive(Antiga Shipyard)-Copy-Copy-Copy-Copy.SC2Replay
- Match 5 - G2 - Symbol vs Golden 2 -Copy-Copy-Copy-Copy.SC2Replay
- Match 3 - G2 - LiquidHerO vs Symbol(Antiga Shipyard)-Copy-Copy-Copy.SC2Replay

I want to create 3 new folders in the same folder that stored those files above that will move the file with the same name at the beginning example Match **num**..... so i want the first 2 files will go to the same folder and the last two will go to two different folders according to different names. 
What should I do? Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with strings, and the filenames always start with the same characters (`Match x -`), you can simply make use of some of the string methods. Namely [`x.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which will return a list of words separated by the first argument.

Example:

```py
filename = "Match 2 - G3 - LiquidHerO vs aLive(DayBreak)-Copy-Copy-Copy.SC2Replay"
directory = filename.split(' - ', maxsplit=1)[0]
# Do something with directory
print(directory)  # Will print Match 2
```

I would invite you in reading the documentation on [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) and follow some [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) in order to learn some of the bases.

You'll most likely need to learn about the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module as well as the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

Comment: I want to scan the file name only **Match num** the other strings It is okay just the first 2 i mentioned and then move it the same or different folders

Comment: Helping you would be easier if you provided the actual script you are working with. Currently, I do not know how good you are with python nor can I give you an appropriate answer. What you are trying to do is fairly simple though, so going through other channels for help would work too (like #python on freenode).

Comment: I edited my answer to be a little be more clear as what split do. However, if you need to learn python, there are multiple other resources online for you to do so. I cannot write your app for you.